# Deleted database & migration file, can't make new migrations nor revert old migrations, what now?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

My workflow with my ASP.NET Core app: Whenever I make changes that affect the database, I revert the old migration, make a new migration, apply it. Because this is still early development I think it makes sense to not pollute the project with lots of migration files. Usually I call this temporary migration file `Initial`, hoping that one of them will actually become the initial migration file.

As a result, I typically have 3 files in my `Data/Migrations` subfolder:

- `00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs` that was provided for me a long time ago by the project template;
- `somenumbers_Initial.cs`;
- `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs`

So the commands I would type in this workflow would look like this, if I remember correctly:

```
Update-Database CreateIdentitySchema
Remove-Migration
Add-Migration Initial
Update-Database
```

This time I made a mistake... I don't remember what exactly happened, I typed something incorrect instead of the above commands and then I was silly enough that (a) manually removing the `Initial` migration file and (b) Dropping the database would be enough to restart the test db from scratch.

I was wrong.

My hopes were that `Add-Migration Initial` would create a valid migration file corresponding to the current state of the models and a subsequent `Update-Database` would recreate the db. Instead this is what happens:

```
PM> Add-Migration initial
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
The name 'initial' is used by an existing migration.
```

??? Really? Well let's try to remove this migration:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.0.0 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
No file named '20190727172711_initial.cs' was found. You must manually remove the migration class 'initial'.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.Literal(String value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GeneratePropertyAnnotations(IProperty property, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateProperty(String builderName, IProperty property, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateProperties(String builderName, IEnumerable`1 properties, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateEntityType(String builderName, IEntityType entityType, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(String builderName, IReadOnlyList`1 entityTypes, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.Generate(String builderName, IModel model, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationsGenerator.GenerateSnapshot(String modelSnapshotNamespace, Type contextType, String modelSnapshotName, IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.RemoveMigration(String projectDir, String rootNamespace, Boolean force, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.RemoveMigration(String contextType, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.RemoveMigrationImpl(String contextType, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.RemoveMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

???? I must manually remove the migration class ?? Where is this migration class?

Let's do some text searching in the project dir... The only interesting file that shows up is `myprojectname.csproj` where I have stuff like this:

```
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\20190412182930_initial.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\20190412182930_initial.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\20190628205310_initial.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\20190628205310_initial.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\20190720205411_initial.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\20190720205411_initial.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\20190720205837_initial.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Data\Migrations\20190720205837_initial.Designer.cs" />
```

I don't think this is relevant here (the numbers strings do not match).

I looked into `ApplicationDbCOntextModelSnapshot` but there seems to be no such class called `initial` there...

What to do now? How to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dropped the database then it's easy. Delete the migrations folder.

Then run

- `add-migration Initial`
- `update-database`

Also, I tend to remove any `<Compile Remove="" />` from the project file.

Comment: I would like `remove-migration` just remove the migration without adding equivalent `<Compile Remove="" />` to the project file. I usually delete them.